# Receive parameter from angular controller to another controller with state.go

Tags: angularjs

I send parameter using `state.go` like:

```
 $state.go("root.detalleregistros", {tipo: "edicion", catalogoid: $scope.catalogo
                });
```

Into controller I want to receive parameter I use:

```
 function detalleRegistrosCtrl($scope, apiService, notificationService, $rootScope, $location, $stateParams, $http, $state) {

        $scope.catalogoid = $stateParams.catalogoid;
```

And my state of controller I want to receive parameter:

```
.state('root.detalleregistros', {
                 url: "detalleRegistros.html",
                 templateUrl: "../SPA/administrador/catalogos/detalleRegistros.html",
                 controller: "detalleRegistrosCtrl",
                 authenticate: true
             })
```

Problem is I don´t receive params into  `$scope.catalogoid = $stateParams.catalogoid;` I always getting `undefined`, can anyone help me there please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your state definition you need to specify there's a param for that route.

```
.state('root.detalleregistros', {
   url: "detalleRegistros/:tipo/:catalogoid",
  //rest of your code
```

Or as Alon pointed out, you can omit them from the url and use params: {

```
.state('root.detalleregistros', {
   url: "detalleRegistros",
   params: {
     tipo: null,
     catalogoid: null
   },
```

Comment: Correct. Or they can use [params](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#params) for default values. or if they don't want to include them in the URL

Comment: But why you use null type?

Comment: That's not the type, that's the default value.

Comment: Yes I get it. Excellent answer. Thanks

Comment: yBrodsky, I received parameter, but no as I want, I receive with format `"{"ID":"1021"}"`, what I need to do to get only number 1021? @AlonEitan

Comment: $stateParams.id should give you 1021. $stateParams should be an object with different properties for each param

Comment: @Gerardo Not sure I understand - Do you want to replace the parameter names of the state?

Comment: Ah? No. Debug $stateParams. What's the output?

Comment: I replace   `$scope.catalogoid = $stateParams.catalogoid;` for   `$scope.catalogoid = $stateParams.id;` but it comes `undefinied`

Comment: You mentioned ID, I was just following your example. You have to use id or whatever your variable is called. Navigate to that page and debug what's inside of $stateParams

Comment: @Gerardo You also need to change `url: "detalleRegistros/:tipo/:catalogoid",` to `url: "detalleRegistros/:tipo/:id",` and/or `catalogoid: null` to `id: null`